# Replace Multiple Quote Tags with respective html in C#

Tags: c#, regex

I have a **multiple quote tag** which i want to replace with a set of **html**.

I have its regex and i have it working for **single quote tag**. But i want to know how it will work for **quote within quotes** tag. The below code is working for single quote tag :

```
Regex rgQP = new Regex(@"(<p>)?\[QUOTE=(.*?)\](</p>)?(.*)(<p>)?\[/QUOTE\](</p>)?");
string singleQuote = "<p>[QUOTE=Simon]</p><p>Testing quote </p><p>[/QUOTE]</p><p>The quick brown fox jumps over the box</p>";

var sq = rgQP.Match(singleQuote);       
string sqauthor = sq.Groups[2].Value;
string sqmsg = sq.Groups[4].Value;

var sqResult = String.Format("<div class=\"blockquote\"><a href=\"test.com\"><small>Posted by {0}</small></a>{1}</div>", sqauthor, sqmsg);
string result = sqResult.ToString();
Console.WriteLine("SingleQuoteResult : {0} ", result); 

//But if I have multiquotes tag like this :

[QUOTE=harris]
[QUOTE=marshal] <p>This is quote by Marshal</p>[/QUOTE] 
<p>This is quote by Harris</p> 
[/QUOTE] 

var expectedres = String.Format("<div class=\"blockquote\"><small>Posted by Harris</small><p>This is quote by Harris</p> <div class=\"blockquote\"><small>Posted by marshal</small><p>This is quote by marshal</p>  </div> </div>");
```

So how can i achieve result like **var expectedres** i.e replacing quote tag with the html :

Can someone guide me

Comment: Why don't you remove the html tags so you can see the nested quote's ?

Comment: which html tags you are talking about ?

Comment: Well, there is no problem handling the nested quote keywords. What is a problem is the placement of the _sqmsg_ in the source text. Is it always in the same place ? Also, imagine what the replacement should look like on the nested one, do that as well. Try to post that.

Comment: I have edited my expected result in var expectedres .. i want the quote tag to replaced with that

Comment: Ok, Im looking at it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this...

Regex

```
 (?s)
 (?>
      \s* 
      (?'Quote'                     #_(4 start)         
           \[ QUOTE=
           ( .*? )                       # (1), Names
           \] 
      )                             #_(4 end)         
      \s* 
      (                             # (2 start), Pre-body
           (?:
                (?! \[ /? QUOTE )
                . 
           )*
      )                             # (2 end)
      \s* 
   |  
      \s* 
      (                             # (3 start), Post-body
           (?:
                (?! \[ /? QUOTE )
                . 
           )*
      )                             # (3 end)
      \s* 
      (?'-Quote'
           \[ /QUOTE \] 
      )
      \s* 
 )+
 (?(Quote)
      (?!)
 )
```

C# sample

```
var str =
    "[QUOTE=harris]\n" +
    "  <p>This is quote by Harris</p>\n" +
    "  [QUOTE=marshal]\n" +
    "    <p>This is quote by Marshal</p>\n" +
    "    [QUOTE=Ted] <p>This is quote by Ted</p>[/QUOTE]\n" +
    "    <p>This is DUP quote by Marshal</p>[/QUOTE]\n" +
    "  <p>This is DUP quote by Harris</p>\n" +
    "[/QUOTE]\n";

var rx = new Regex(@"(?s)(?>\s*(?'Quote'\[QUOTE=(.*?)\])\s*((?:(?!\[/?QUOTE).)*)\s*|\s*((?:(?!\[/?QUOTE).)*)\s*(?'-Quote'\[/QUOTE\])\s*)+(?(Quote)(?!))");

Match M = rx.Match(str);
if (M.Success)
{
    CaptureCollection ccNames = M.Groups[1].Captures;  // Names
    CaptureCollection ccPre = M.Groups[2].Captures;    // Pre body
    CaptureCollection ccPost = M.Groups[3].Captures;   // Post body

    Console.WriteLine("Match = {0}", M.ToString());

    int cnt = ccNames.Count;

    String sDiv = "<div class=\"blockquote\">";
    String htmlOut = "";

    String sTab = "";

    for (int i = 0; i < cnt; i++)
    {
        String name = ccNames[i].Value.Trim();
        String Pre = ccPre[i].Value.Trim();
        String Post = ccPost[cnt - i - 1].Value.Trim();

        Console.WriteLine("{0} Name {1}", i, name);
        Console.WriteLine("\t{0} Pre {1}", i, Pre);
        Console.WriteLine("\t{0} Post {1}", cnt-i-1, Post);

        // Format output

        htmlOut += "\n" + sTab + sDiv + "\n";

        sTab += "\t";
        htmlOut += sTab + "<small>Posted by " +name + "</small>";

        String scratch = "";
        if ( Pre.Length > 0)
            scratch += "\n" + sTab + Pre;
        if ( Post.Length > 0)
            scratch += "\n" + sTab + Post;
        htmlOut += scratch;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < cnt; i++)
    {
        sTab = "";
        for ( int k = 0; k < (cnt-i-1); k++ )
            sTab += "\t";
        htmlOut += "\n" + sTab + "</div>";
    }

    Console.WriteLine("------------------");
    Console.WriteLine("{0}", htmlOut);
}
```

Output

```
   Match =
   [QUOTE=harris]
     <p>This is quote by Harris</p>
     [QUOTE=marshal]
       <p>This is quote by Marshal</p>
       [QUOTE=Ted] <p>This is quote by Ted</p>[/QUOTE]
       <p>This is DUP quote by Marshal</p>[/QUOTE]
     <p>This is DUP quote by Harris</p>
   [/QUOTE]

   0 Name harris
           0 Pre <p>This is quote by Harris</p>
           2 Post <p>This is DUP quote by Harris</p>
   1 Name marshal
           1 Pre <p>This is quote by Marshal</p>
           1 Post <p>This is DUP quote by Marshal</p>
   2 Name Ted
           2 Pre <p>This is quote by Ted</p>
           0 Post
   ------------------

   <div class="blockquote">
           <small>Posted by harris</small>
           <p>This is quote by Harris</p>
           <p>This is DUP quote by Harris</p>
           <div class="blockquote">
                   <small>Posted by marshal</small>
                   <p>This is quote by Marshal</p>
                   <p>This is DUP quote by Marshal</p>
                   <div class="blockquote">
                           <small>Posted by Ted</small>
                           <p>This is quote by Ted</p>
                   </div>
           </div>
   </div>
```

Comment: The solution worked.. thanks.. but if I have some text after [/QUOTE] tag .. how I'll get it .. is it some changes in regex ?